# Shopify liquid - collection object is empty in theme.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want to add breadcrumbs to new shopify eshop according to this [Liquid code example](https://shopify.github.io/liquid-code-examples/example/breadcrumb-navigation). Problem is that `collection` object is empty when I am on product page (case `{%- when 'product' -%}`).

Console log in this case returns `undefined`:

```
...
{%- when 'product' -%}
  <script>console.log({{ collection | json }});</script>
  {%- if collection.url -%}
    <li class="breadcrumbs__item">
      {{ collection.title | link_to: collection.url }}
    </li>
  {%- endif -%}
  <li class="breadcrumbs__item">
    <a class="breadcrumbs__link" href="{{ product.url }}" aria-current="page">{{ product.title }}</a>
  </li>
{%- when 'collection' and collection.handle -%}
...
```

I use conditional collections and product is usually in multiple collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `collection` objetc is empty when you're in the product page. What collection do you need?

If you need any collection that contains the current product you can do

```
{% assign collection = product.collections.first %}
```

And then you will have the collection assigned to the `collection` variable.

Comment: Thank you this is what I need. Is there any priorities in this `product.collections`? I need to avoid collections like "sales", "bestsellers", ... to show in breadcrumb navigation. Also "detective books" has higher priority than "books".

Comment: @JakubJuřena what you can do is cycle through them and skip the collections you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you're adding `<script>console.log('log')</script>` inside a liquid capture, in my case I removed those and it solved my strip issue.